# How to make MySQL character_set_connection work with utf16?

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

This query works fine:

```
set character_set_client = utf8
```

Same goes for [utf8mb4, big5, dec8, cp850, hp8, koi8r, latin1, latin2, swe7, ascii, ujis, sjis, hebrew, etc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html).

However, when I tried `set character_set_client = utf16` or `set character_set_client = utf32`, they don't work:

> #1231 - Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'utf16'
>
> #1231 - Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'utf32'

Why don't the commands work?

How can we make MySQL [`character_set_client`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_client) work with utf16/32?

Comment: Mysql version? As mysql says: MySQL 5.5.3. is the minimum to do that

Comment: @MarcoMura, Mine is `5.5.40-0ubuntu0.12.04.1`. MySQL docs only stated `ucs2` cannot be used: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_connection . weird eh, I'm suspecting it's a multibyte thing, though the MySQL docs is severely undocumented.

Comment: It doesn't recognize it. Question: Do you launch that command from mysql client or with php code?

Comment: @MarcoMura, phpMyAdmin console (v 4.1.0). `show character set` is showing both `utf16` and `utf32`.

Comment: Maybe it's a phpMyAdmin Issue. Have you tried putting utf16 between single quotes?

Comment: @MarcoMura, I've tested with quotes too. It's not a phpMyAdmin issue, the other inputs e.g.  utf8mb4, big5, dec8, cp850, hp8, koi8r, latin1, latin2, swe7, ascii, ujis, sjis, hebrew, etc are working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

> MySQL docs only stated ucs2 cannot be used:

That was the 5.0 doc link. 5.5 [says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_client):

> ucs2, utf16, and utf32 cannot be used as a client character set

and 5.6 adds `utf16le`. Essentially MySQL expects queries to be in an ASCII-compatible encoding, each doc version here lists the ASCII-incompatible encodings that version of MySQL knows about.

Is there any particular reason you prefer to use UTF-16? It's generally a bad choice for anything other than talking to other UTF-16 environments (Win32 API, Java etc).

Comment: So basically you mean that all multibyte charsets are "banned"?

Comment: Not multibyte exactly—UTF-8, Big-5 and Shift-JIS are all supported multibyte encodings, for example. But the encoding must encode the ASCII characters to the first 128 bytes, which UTF-16/32 don't do because of all the zero bytes.

Comment: `character_set_client` simply sets  the charset for statements that arrive from the client, Why must they be ascii-compatible? I don't see any harm in allowing statements in utf16/32.

Comment: My guess would be their SQL parser works natively in ASCII and only does charset processing when it hits a literal or schema name.

Comment: @bobince can u just let me know answer for my question related to charset  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495646/database-charset-utf16-not-showing-proper-character